# Chrome extension - Notifications not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Currently trying to produce a notification but I'm struggling.. I've done quite a bit of googling, but seem to find no solution.

Since you can't use notifications within content_scripts I've had to attempt a work around..

Example of code:

manifest.json:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
"permissions": [
    "notifications"
],
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["*://*/*"],
        "js": ["alert.js"]
    }
]
```

alert.js

```
window.onload = function()
{

if(document.body.innerHTML.toString().indexOf('Google') > -1 {

    alert("Hello");

    chrome.extension.sendRequest({msg: "Sup?"}, function(response) {
        console.log(response.returnMsg);
    });
}

};
```

background.js:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

    var notify = {
        type: "basic",
        iconUrl: "icon.png",
        title: "Google",
        message: "Welcome to google",
    };

    notify.show();

    setTimeout(function(){ notify.cancel(); },5000);
    sendResponse({returnMsg: "All good!"});
}
);
```

Comment: `chrome.extension.sendRequest` is deprecated. See this : https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-sendRequest

Comment: `notify` is an object you created from scratch so it doesn't have `show` method. Study the [example extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:notifications.create) that shows the correct usage of the notifications API.